# CAST(NULL AS DATE)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a view in oracle which is already defined in DB2,in the DB2 view all date column having cast function , Below i have created a view by taking one date column from the view. Note:COBDATE column having number datatype as for the design. i am getting ORA-00936:missing expression error.

```
Create View MYVIEWV1 as (Select
A.COBDATE                   ,
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
 (case when (COBDATE = 0)
  then  CAST(NULL AS DATE)
  else
   date(SUBSTR(COBDATE,1,4) ||
   '-'||SUBSTR(COBDATE,5,2) ||
   '-'||SUBSTR(COBDATE,7,2))
       end )  as    COBDATE2 
from MYTBLT1 A;
```

please suggest how i can convert this to oracle syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cast` isn't the issue, though it isn't really needed. The 'missing expression' error is reported against line 7 column 4, which is the call to the `date()` function - which doesn't exist in Oracle. It's expecting a date literal to follow the keyword `date`, not parentheses or function arguments.

You can use the `to_date()` function instead, with a format model matching the way you're constructing the first argument. You said `cobdate` is a number but you're treating it as a string so I'll continue to do that implicitly...

```
create table mytblt1 (cobdate number);
insert into mytblt1 values (20141225);
insert into mytblt1 values (0);

create view myviewv1 as
select cobdate,
  case when cobdate = 0
    then null -- or with unnecessary cast: cast(null as date)
  else
    to_date(substr(cobdate,1,4)
        ||'-'||substr(cobdate,5,2)
        ||'-'||substr(cobdate,7,2),
      'YYYY-MM-DD')
  end as cobdate2 
from mytblt1;

select * from myviewv1;

   COBDATE COBDATE2          
---------- -------------------
  20141225 2014-12-25 00:00:00 
         0                     

desc myviewv1

Name     Null Type   
-------- ---- ------ 
COBDATE       NUMBER 
COBDATE2      DATE
```

With a cut-down date format model - so you don't have to worry about the `-` separators - you can simplify it further:

```
create view myviewv1 as
select cobdate,
  case when cobdate = 0
    then null -- cast(null as date)
  else
    to_date(cobdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
  end as cobdate2 
from mytblt1;
```

Or you can move the `case` inside the function call:

```
create view myviewv1 as
select cobdate,
  to_date(case when cobdate = 0 then null else cobdate end, 'YYYYMMDD') as cobdate2 
from mytblt1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Nulls don't need casting. Just use `NULL` on its own.

```
case when COBDATE = 0 then NULL
else <some date> end as COBDATE2
```

Don't need all those brackets either.